# Mod Rewrite & CheckSpelling/CheckCase redirect solution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a number of pages setup, to be accessed by clients' guests.  The problem being, case sensitive URLs.

Currently I have in my htaccess file (to remove the .php)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

for example: (the target file is ClientName.php)
`website.com/rsvp/ClientName`  <-this works, and the file is ClientName.php
`website.com/rsvp/clientname`  <-this serves a Internal Server Error

-- edit/update --

Adding both `CheckSpelling on` & `CheckCaseOnly on` does not work, unless the .php is in the url. No combination of the two [mod_spelling & mod_rewrite] would work. I also found out, I do not have RewriteMap

based on this [thread/post](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?203011-mod-rewrite-to-lower-case&s=8574683c9aa60a214e6d986345b7f463&p=1464198&viewfull=1#post1464198) can I redirect to a php file rather than the 500 error page if the file does not exist? (or edit my 500 error page?)

from the post;

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([a-z0-9/]*)\.html
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ redir.php?p=$1 [L]
> ```
>
> Will examine the {REQUEST_URI} string and EXCLUDE (!) everything that's lowercase (or directory -- see the "/"?) .html then rewrite EVERYTHING.html to the redir script. Ahhhhh! I just added the "0-9" in there to handle your digits, too. Remember, these "excluded" strings are the ones you want to PASS through to your pages and NOT rewrite.

Comment: Do you have access to Apache config?

Comment: no, this particular site in on hostgator shared hosting.  They list mod_spelling as installed, but I am not sure how to test it